# Get last week's dates only for Monday and Sunday

Tags: c#

I am trying t get last week's working date that is Monday and Sunday. The following syntax gives me the current week's Monday but not last week's.

```
  DateTime thisMonday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

I am struggling to get last week's Monday's and Sunday's only dates and not the time.

Comment: linq works on collection-like types - what is the struggle?

Comment: [DateTime.Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-5.0)

Comment: You know how to get this weeks monday but not how to subtract 7 days?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It didn't clicked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not the time

[`DateTime.Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=net-5.0) only gives you a date at 0:00. [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-5.0) gives you the same date including time.

> I am struggling to get last week's Monday's and Sunday's

Just subtract 1 week ...

```
DateTime thisMonday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Monday);
DateTime lastMonday = thisMonday.AddDays(-7);
Console.WriteLine(lastMonday);
```

If you dislike the magic number 7, you might use

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Length
```